# Code run in STS has no issues, crashes when run from command line

Tags: java, maven

I am sure this is an easy configuration issue of some kind but I can not find it. When I run my java code in STS

```
Spring Tool Suite 

Version: 3.8.3.RELEASE
Build Id: 201612191457
Platform: Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2)
```

All runs well. No errors, no issues. The code does everything it should.

When I build the jar with mvn package from the command line and then try to run it I get:

```
2017-07-17 19:04:55,805 4523  ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-3 - Failed to execute isValid() for connection, co\

nfigure connection test query (com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.isValid(I)Z). 

Exception in thread "ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-1" 2017-07-17 19:04:55,807 4525  ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-2 -\

 Failed to execute isValid() for connection, configure connection test query (com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.isValid(I)Z). 

2017-07-17 19:04:55,807 4525  ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Failed to execute isValid() for connection, co\

nfigure connection test query (com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.isValid(I)Z). 

2017-07-17 19:04:55,807 4525  ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-4 - Failed to execute isValid() for connection, co\

nfigure connection test query (com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.isValid(I)Z). 

Exception in thread "ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-1" Exception in thread "ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-1" Exception in thread "ThreadPoolTaskEx\

ecutor-1" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.isValid(I)Z

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkDriverSupport(PoolBase.java:434)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:405)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:363)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
```

I have checked everything I know to check and am at a loss. I feel like this must be a build setting someplace I have missed but I can not find anything.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>GroupID</groupId>
    <artifactId>ArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>name</name>
    <description>description</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
            <version>10.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>20030203.000129</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isValid method was added in JDBC 4.0.

issue in added dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
        <version>10.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

you need to use :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
    <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
    <version>10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to download the 10.1 driver from IBM, but doing that with your change did it.